# How to take user input in SharePoint 2010 wokflow on a custom list?

Tags: sharepoint, workflow, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-workflow

I have a business requirement where i need to create a workflow on a custom list where i may have 20-30 custom fields.

My question is that in a sharepoint state machine workflow , how do i incorporate User's feedback / comment he may want to give to a user at any level in the worflow. E.g. When a Person at level A submits the proposal to Person at level B, he will fill in all the custom fields but along with it he also need to send some comments/Recomandation to higher authority. Person at level B shoudl also be able to send back the proposal along with some comments/Suggestion. Sending comments/queries/suggestion...should be possible from one workflow state to any worflow state.

Thanks,
Nikhil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that in your WF the item moves from state to state as the result of users approving/rejected tasks assigned to them? This is the usual way anyhow. You can add additional metadata fields to those task and ask for feeback. Then you can use this data in emails, alerts, whatever you need

Comment: Vladi, thanks for your response. How do i display only certain additional fields on the task form based on the level of document reviewer ? I mean different type of user should see different type of fields.

Comment: Each task is usually of a distinct content type, this way you control which columns each task has. Each reviewer can receieve tasks of different type. If you need something else, say the same content type for each reviewer, but still viewing different columns, you can use some sort of column permissions add-on, such as our Smart List Pro (http://www.infowisesolutions.com/product.aspx?id=SmartListPro